# Handling JSON registries with MongoDB

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask

I have created a Flask service and I'm having a trouble on parsing some JSON values which are stored in MongoDB. I know how to parse every object which has a single value expect the address parameter which has more values inside (e.g `"address":[{"street":"Jardine Place","city":"Lowgap","postcode":...`)

**JSON file:**

```
{"name":"Morton Fitzgerald","email":"mortonfitzgerald@ontagene.com","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1997"},"address":[{"street":"Jardine Place","city":"Lowgap","postcode":{"$numberInt":"18330"}}]}
{"name":"Dorthy Cobb","email":"dorthycobb@ontagene.com","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1994"}}
```

In the python script, I'm trying to find a student based on the email, which I'm giving to the body at Postman. After that, if a student with an `address` is found I need to return a message with every value inside the `"address"` except the `"city"`. With the following code, I'm taking some results but from them, I need to print out only the `"street"` and `"postcode"`.

**Python function:**

```
@app.route('/getStudentAddress', methods=['GET'])
def get_student_address():
    # Request JSON data
    data = None 
    try:
        data = json.loads(request.data)
        uuid = request.headers.get('authorization')
    except Exception as e:
        return Response("bad json content",status=500,mimetype='application/json')
    if data == None:
        return Response("bad request",status=500,mimetype='application/json')
    if not "email" in data:
        return Response("Information incomplete",status=500,mimetype="application/json")

    if (is_session_valid(uuid)):
        student = students.find_one({"email":data['email']})
        if(student != None):
            student = students.find_one({"address":student['address']})
            if(student != None):
                student = {'name':student["name"],'address':student["address"]}
                return Response(json.dumps(student), status=200, mimetype='application/json')
        else:
            return Response("Not-found", status=400, mimetype='application/json')
    else: 
        return Response("Not authenticated user", status=401, mimetype='application/json')
```

**Results:**

```
{"name": "Morton Fitzgerald", "address": [{"street": "Jardine Place", "city": "Lowgap", "postcode": 18330}]}
```

**Error:**

If I choose a registry like `{"name":"Dorthy Cobb","email":"dorthycobb@ontagene.com","yearOfBirth":{"$numberInt":"1994"}}` which doesn't have an address I'm taking an error of `KeyError: 'address'`

Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to handle the case `if not 'address' in student:`, right?

Comment: Yes @TimRoberts you are right. If there isn't an 'address' registry I get the Key Error. Also, if it has a 'address' registry I need to print the following: 'street' and 'postcode' but I don't know how.

Comment: Your `address` key is a list, so you'll have to decide which address to use.  (I assume the first.)  So, `student['address'][0]['street']` and `student['address'][0]['postcode']`, right?  That does assume every address has a street and postcode.

Comment: I understood what you wrote on this comment @Tim Roberts. Unfortunately, these two registries of JSON that I introduced are examples. The JSON file is huge so I can't parse a parameter of integer to get a certain one.

Comment: What choice do you have?  If you have a list of addresses, then you have to choose one.  Unless you have a metric to help you choose, the first is as good as any.

Comment: The only metric that I have it's the student variable which has been found with find_one method but I don't know in which line that student is. So I can't use the parameter 0.

Comment: But `find_one` gives you the whole row, right?  So why can't you do `student['address'][0]` as I said?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider adding a "try to fetch" function that checks to see if the key exists and provides a default value:

```
def tryfetch( container, key, default=None ):
    return container[key] if key in container else default
```

That way, you can write things like::

```
    address = tryfetch( student, "address" )
    if address:
        addr = tryfetch(address[0], "street", "NA") + tryfetch(address[0], "postcode", "NA")
```

Comment: That's also a good idea that will help me in other projects, but I can't create the tryfetch function because I don't have a permission to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your time and the solution